# Odd behavior when randomly choosing function from list and testing which function it was

Tags: python, random

Suppose I have these two functions:

```
def f1():
    pass

def f2():
    pass
```

If I want to run one of these two functions at random, I can do this:

```
flist = (f1, f2)
function = random.choice(flist)()
```

Unfortunatley, when I want to test which function it was using an if statement...

```
if function == f1:
    print "Good"
```

`Good` is not outputted. Why?

Comment: You'll need to give an example showing what `list_thing` is and what is inside it.

Comment: Show the list and the code with the if or while.

Comment: Are you trying to do `if var = random.choice(list_thing)()`?

Comment: @user2357112 I have edited my question, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: The two code snippets do different things.  `var` is bound to the function object in the first snippet, it is bound to the *return value* of `var` in the second.

Comment: @BrenBarn Edited the question, hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: what are function1 and function2?

Comment: @Padraic_Cunningham they are functions stored in __list_thing__ that I decided not to show in the code because it wasn't neccesary.

Comment: @Padraic_Cunningham they are functions stored in list_thing that I decided not to show in the code because they didn't need to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As roippi commented, your two blocks of code store different values in `var`. In the first version, you're storing the function you've chosen in `var` (and when you call it with `var()`, you discard the return value). In the second block, you call the function immediately after choosing it, and `var` gets assigned the function's return value (which probably makes your comparisons against the functions not useful).

The second block of code is equivalent to this modified version of the first block:

```
list_thing = [function1, function2]
var = random.choice(list_thing)
var2 = var()              # call the chosen function, and save its return value  as var2
if var2 == function1:     # compare against var2, rather than var here
    #Do something
elif var2 == function2:   # here too
    #Do something else
```

Unless your functions may return themselves (or each other), the second version of the code is probably not what you want. Without knowing what the functions do, or what your `#Do something` blocks mean, it's not easy to say what you should do. An alternative, I suppose would be to wrap up  the function call along with the `# something` in another function, then make your choice between the wrapper functions:

```
def function1_and_something():
    function1()
    #Do something

def function2_and_something_else():
    function2()
    #Do something else

random.choice([function1_and_something, function2_and_something_else])() # chose and call
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the functions are or exactly what you want to do I have just made them strings to illustrate how to use random.choice and compare values.

```
import random
list_thing = ["function1", "function2"]
var = random.choice(list_thing)
if var == "function1":
    print "var is equal function1"
elif var == "function2":
    print "var is equal to function12"
```

Comment: I think this answer is not very helpful (though it seems the questioner may disagree with me). The issue with the non-working code in the question was that `var` was getting the return value of whichever function was picked, rather than the function itself in the working version.

Comment: It was not very clear what the OP wanted and you can see from his syntax errors like `var = random.choice(list_thing)()` that he needed to be shown how to use the correct  syntax before as much as anything else.

Comment: Um, my point is that `random.choice(list_thing)()` is not necessarily an error. If the list is a list of functions, this expression picks one and calls it (with no arguments). The issue seemed to be that the expression's value is the *return value of the function*, rather than the function itself (so you can't compare `var` to the function usefully).

Comment: I know `random.choice(list_thing)()` is not necessarily an error but the fact the OP used `var()` and  `if var == function1:` also makes it seem logical to me that he was not sure what he was doing.

Comment: Well, you're certainly right that it's not very clear what the questioner wanted. Our debate has motivated me to make my own answer. Hopefully between our two answers the issue can be fully understood and resolved!

Comment: Yes indeed, I did ask  what the functions were so I could give a more specific answer but the OP said the functions didn't think they were important.